# Applied statistics for scientists and engineers: Probability- Independence

Tags: probability, independence

A musician is currently producing three different songs. Let $A_i$ denote the event that song $i$ is completed by the end of the week, where $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. It is known these three events are independent with probabilities $P(A_1) = 0.4$, $P(A_2) = 0.3$, $P(A_3) = 0.1$. What is the probability that at most one of the three songs is completed by the end of the week?

This is what I thought, but I got it wrong:
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)=0.012$$
The answer given was $0.456$
I don't know how else to do this problem.

*I understand how to do this now, I'm trying to figure out if it asks for exactly one. I thought it was what was P((A_1 n A_2'n A_3')U(A_1'n A_2n A_3')U(A_1'n A_2'n A_3))
But I think that works for "at most one" not "exactly one".

Comment: I fixed your question to be written in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please take a look at the link to see how to properly format your question for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its at most one of the three songs :-

P(Answer)= Probability of song 1 alone being published + Probability of song 2 alone being published + Probability of song 3 alone being published

```
     = .4*(1-.3)*(1-.1) + (1-.4)*.3*(1-.1) + (1-.4)*(1-.3)*.1

     = .456
```

But i agree with the @ConMan the should be another event where no one publishes a song this is how you get your answer

I think the question should be only one(exactly one) of the three songs published

Comment: Thanks. Would you know what to do if it asks for "exactly one" instead of "at most one"?

Comment: the above answer is for  "exactly one "

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find the probability that *at most one song* is completed, which is the same as finding the probability that *exactly zero or one song* is completed. Which means you're looking for two things:

1. The probability that zero songs are completed. (Which is the event $A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c$, where $X^c$ is the complement of event $X$, i.e. it's the event "$X$ doesn't happen".)
2. The probability that one song is completed but the other two aren't. So it's the combination of three events: the event that only $A_1$ is completed, i.e. $A_1 \cup A_2^c \cup A_3^c$, the event that only $A_2$ is completed, i.e. $A_1^c \cup A_2 \cup A_3^c$, and the event that only $A_3$ is completed, i.e. $A_1^c \cup A_2^c \cup A_3$.

The event that you calculated the probability of, $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$, is the event of "$A_1$ is completed *and* $A_2$ is completed *and* $A_3$ is completed", i.e. the event of all three songs being completed.

You should be able to calculate the probabilities of the 4 events I've outlined, noting that all of them are mutually exclusive (meaning that once you've found the separate probabilities, the probability of any of them occurring is their sum).

Comment: Thank you, it makes so much sense now.